# If back-end is not working, what pages does front-end show?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend

I'm making some pages with React and spring boot.

But, i had one question while making this page.

If some unknown problems occured, server send 500 Internal Server Error or nothing.

In this case, what the pages does React show?

Just show block page? like "oops... there's something wrong...."
or show alert modal or something else?

If you advice to me, it'll be very helpful for me.

Thank you for reading this question.

Answer (score 0):

if server returns 500 Internal Server error then you should display the error message from server to the user using modal or fixed block area at the ui that represent the error message like from top, bottom...
if user required any page that not found in routes then you should have 404 page that tell the user that no page found with this url.